# which webpack loader to use with a spawned binary in an electron-vue application?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron

I am developing an electron-vue applicaton which requires the main process to spawn a binary (mac) in order to retrieve some JSON and pass it back to the renderer process (vue).

I'm new to this structure, so please be gentle.

I have the interprocess communications working ok, however when I attempt to fire this all up, I am seeing a bundling error with webpack requiring me to use a loader to handle the binary. I assume this is a packaging issue, however I am unsure as to what loader configuration is required.

### Code section:

```
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    ipcMain.on('ondropfile', (event, filePath) =>
      const ltcScan = spawn("./bin/ltcscan",["-c1",filePath]);
      ltcScan.stdout.on("data", data => {
        console.log(data)
        var ltcscanData = JSON.parse(data)
        event.reply('got-ltcscan', ltcscanData)
      })
    })
  })
```

### Error output

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (47:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
|   win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
|     ipcMain.on('ondropfile', (event, filePath) =>
>       const ltcScan = spawn("./bin/ltcscan",["-c1",filePath]);
|       ltcScan.stdout.on("data", data => {
|         console.log(data)
```

Unfortunately the indicated documentation section doesn't really make clear what to do in the case of a spawned binary.

EDIT:

Further to this, vue-cli appears to embed the webpack configuration so that the only way to change it is to modify vue.config.js by adding a specific section.

This is what I came up with for starters:

```
let  CopyPlugin  = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      removeElectronJunk: false
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: './resources/mac/bin/ltcscan', to: './dist_electron/mac/bin/ltcscan' }
        ]
      })
    ]
  }
}
```